# Flash Security Setting Violation - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We have implemented charting functionality in our Oracle APEX application using AnyChart. Currently there is an internal URL (accessed internally from within the firewall) from which the APEX application and embedded charting functionality is working fine.

We have a proxy URL (which is pointing to the internal URL) and from this proxy URL we are able to access the website but getting a Flash Error on the pages where AnyChart is implemented. The error is -

> Flash Security Error AnyChart cannot be launched due to Flash Security
>   settings Violation Please refer to Security Error Article in AnyChart
>   documentation to fix this issue Click for more information

As per the documentation on the Flash website, we created a `crossdomain.xml` file and placed it in the root folder of the server.

However the above mentioned error still occurs.

This is a very critical situation for us since the website has to go live in a couple of days. We would appreciate any help, assistance or guidance that you can provide

Thank you

Nomad

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd option described here: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/avoiding-flash-chart-security-warning.html

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, the solution worked. Since you didn't enter this as a solution I cant accept it. But why don't you? I will accept it as the solution. Thanks once again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the alternative solutions here: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/avoiding-flash-chart-security-warning.html

Quoted:

> My solution is to create an application item called BASE_URL that is
>   initialized with the right URL basing on the setting of a build
>   option. As i am already used to have a PRODUCTION build option in all
>   applications enabling certain features like visitor tracking and
>   google ads when its status is include, I simply created a couple of
>   mutually exclusive application computations that run "on new instance"
>   and update the value of BASE_URL with the static value
>   http://www.somedomain.com/apex when PRODUCTION's status is include or
>   the PL/SQL expression  'http://' || owa_util.get_cgi_env('HTTP_HOST')
>   || owa_util.get_cgi_env('SCRIPT_NAME') || '/' when the status is
>   exclude.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks once again Jeffrey